# Using Wireshark with remote interface

Tags: ssh, wireshark

I have a remote containter that I log on into using SSH, and want to capture its traffic with Wireshark.

In mac or linux environemts I could write

```
ssh remote-ssh-host 'sudo tcpdump -U -i eth1 -w -' | wireshark -i - -k
```

Does someone know the windows equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CaptureSetup/Pipes](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes) article has some named FIFO examples for Windows, and mentions that Wireshark supports reading the capture from a TCP connection, not only from a pipe.

1. Start the capture and pipe it into a TCP listener:

   ```
   ssh -L 12345:127.0.0.1:12345 root@host "socat -u exec:'tcpdump -U -w - -i eth1' tcp-l:12345,bind=127.0.0.1"
   ```

   or

   ```
   ssh -L 12345:127.0.0.1:12345 root@host "tcpdump -U -w - -i eth1 | nc -v -l -s 127.0.0.1 -p 12345"
   ```
2. Separately, start Wireshark:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\Wireshark\Wireshark.exe" -k -i TCP@127.0.0.1:12345
   ```

If you don't have OpenSSH on Windows, but do have PuTTY, then replace `ssh` with `plink` (or possibly `plink -no-antispoof`); all other options remain the same.